# Images uploaded to the media library has strange colors. However, in the edit screen the color is ok

Tags: images, uploads, media, media-library

This is a strange issue that I've never encountered before. When I upload this image to WordPress' media library, it comes out like this (image on the left):

[image: Notice the image on the left.]

This is also how the image appears on the front end.

However, when I click on that image and edit it, it looks correct like this:

[image]

Here is the image in question:

[image]

If you open that image up in Photoshop, you will see that it's not CMYK, but RGB which should work. I've worked with images/Photoshop for a long time and have never come across this. Can someone help me figure this out?